# Create a new stream from a stream in Dart

Tags: stream, dart, future

I suspect that my understanding of `Stream`s in Dart might have a few holes in it...

I have a situation in which I'd like a Dart app to respond to intermittent input (which immediately suggests the use of `Streams`s -- or `Future`s, maybe). I can implement the behavior I want with *listener* functions but I was wondering how to do this in a better, more Dart*esque* way.

As a simple example, the following (working) program listens to keyboard input from the user and adds a div element to the document containing what has been typed since the previous space, whenever the space bar is hit.

```
import  'dart:html';

main() {
  listenForSpaces(showInput);
}

void  listenForSpaces(void  Function(String) listener) {
  var input =  List<String>();
  document.onKeyDown.listen((keyboardEvent) {
    var key = keyboardEvent.key;
    if (key ==  " ") {
      listener(input.join());
      input.clear();
    } else {
      input.add(key.length >  1  ?  "[$key]"  : key);
    }
  });
}

void  showInput(String message) {
  document.body.children.add(DivElement()..text = message);
}
```

What I'd like to be able to do is to create a new `Stream` from the `Stream` that I'm listening to (in the example above, to create a new `Stream` from `onKeyDown`). In other words, I might set the program above out as:

```
var myStream = ...
myStream.listen(showInput);
```

I suspect that there is a way to create a `Stream` and then, at different times and places, insert elements to it or call for it to emit a value: it feels as though I am missing something simple. In any case, any help or direction to documentation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating a new stream from an existing stream is fairly easy with an `async*` function.
For a normal stream, I would just do:

```
Stream<String> listenForSpaces() async* {
  var input = <String>[];
  await for (var keyboardEvent in document.onKeyDown) {
    var key = keyboardEvent.key;
    if (key == " ") {
      yield input.join();
      input.clear();
    } else {
      input.add(key.length > 1 ? "[$key]" : key);
    }
  }
}
```

The `async*` function will propagate pauses through to the underlying stream, and it may potentially pause the source during the `yield`.
That may or may not be what you want, since pausing a DOM event stream can cause you to miss events. For a DOM stream, I'd probably prefer to go with the `StreamController` based solution above.

Answer (score 1):

There are several methods and there is a whole package [`rxdart`](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/rxdart) to allow all kinds of things.

Only the final consumer should use `listen` and only if you need to explicitly want to unsubscribe, otherwise use `forEach`

If you want to manipulate events like in your example, use `map`.

Comment: Upvoted for pointing me to rxdart. I'm still holding out for an explicit answer, though! :)

Comment: Not sure what the question is you're expecting an explicit answer for.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't originally planning to answer my own question but I have since found a very simple answer to this question in the [dartlang creating streams](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/libraries/creating-streams) article; in case it's helpful to others:

Specifically, if we'd like to create a stream that we can insert elements into at arbitrary times and places in the code, we can do so via the [StreamController](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-async/StreamController-class.html) class. Instances of this class have an `add` method; we can simply use the instance's `stream` property as our stream.

As an example, the code in my question could be rewritten as:

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:async';

main() async {
  // The desired implementation stated in the question:
  var myStream = listenForSpaces();
  myStream.listen(showInput);
}

Stream<String> listenForSpaces() {
  // Use the StreamController class.
  var controller = StreamController<String>();

  var input = List<String>();
  document.onKeyDown.listen((keyboardEvent) {
    var key = keyboardEvent.key;
    if (key == " ") {
      // Add items to the controller's stream.
      controller.add(input.join());
      input.clear();
    } else {
      input.add(key.length > 1 ? "[$key]" : key);
    }
  });

  // Listen to the controller's stream.
  return controller.stream;
}

void showInput(String message) {
  document.body.children.add(DivElement()..text = message);
}
```

(As mentioned in the article, we need to be careful if we want to set up a stream from scratch like this because there is nothing to stop us from inserting items to streams that don't have associated, active subscribers; inserted items would in that case be buffered, which could result in a memory leak.)